# Why doesn't Jupyter lab set required conda environment paths properly (IMHO)?

Tags: python, conda, jupyter-lab

In an attempt to simplify and improve my python experience I use conda to manage environments and switch between them.  In addition I use Jupyter Lab with multiple python kernels each with different sets of packages.

Consider this simple set of environments...

```
(base) PS C:\Users\xxx> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3
jupyter                  C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\jupyter
spatial                  C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial
```

The environment jupyter has the jupyter package installed (and little else) and spatial contains all the useful stuff like numpy, scipy etc and ipykernel and has been registered as a kernel for Jupyter.

I activate the jupyter environment in a powershell, select the spatial kernel and open a notebook.

All is well until I try to import numpy where upon I get a dll failing to load (and a lot of advice on how to fix it but I think the reason is simple if hard to fix).

So I run the same conda environment in a powershell and try to import numpy; nothing, all is fine.

**So what happens...**

When conda switches python environments it rewrites the PATH environment variable so that the python process that gets launched comes from that environment AND so that it can then see the correct path to the numpy dlls (or any other package dlls you might want).

When I activate my 'spatial' environment in a **powershell** and sneak a look at PATH I see this at the top...

```
(spatial) PS C:\Users\xxx> $env:PATH -split ";"
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial\Library\bin
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial\Scripts
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\envs\spatial\bin
C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\condabin
C:\Windows\system32
```

**Nary a mention of the Jupyter environment anywhere in the PATH.**

If however I look at the PATH (os.environ['PATH'].split(';') not sys.path) within the python environment 'spatial' when running inside **Jupyter** I see...

```
['C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter\\Library\\usr\\bin',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter\\Library\\bin',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\envs\\jupyter\\bin',
 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Miniconda3\\condabin',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32',
 'C:\\Windows'
```

**No PATH to any dll that exists anywhere but the Jupyter environment itself.  So numpy cannot find it's dlls.**

The upshot of this means that you can't have packages in separate python environments running inside Jupyter Lab that need dlls.  Or rather you need to install all those packages AND their dlls in the conda environment running Jupyter Lab AS WELL as the environment you need to use them in.  So you cannot for instance have two versions of numpy in separate environments (unless by luck the dlls are all the same).

***What am I missing?***

Answer (score 0):

What looks like a solution is the package [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels).

This needs to be installed in the conda environment you activate to run Jupyter Lab.

Kernels will then have names in the Jupyter Lab launcher like Python[conda env:spatial].

The PATH seems to be correctly set and dlls load properly.

My problems / confusion was down to my apparent earlier success in getting kernels to work (to a degree) inside Jupyter Lab using only...

```
python -m ipykernel install
```

**Do not do this.** It seems is only partially effective (your environment may run but you may have serious problems down the line - missing dlls etc).

You still need the ipykernel package installed in each conda environment you want to use within Jupyer Lab but rely on the nb_conda_kernels package to find them when Jupyter Lab is started and present them (on the Jupyter Launcher page or available kernels drop down).